# React native navigation undefine object error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**I am facing a error called "undefine is not an object (evaluating '_this.props'). Its a very simple code which i am using the modern function of react native. I am not using class here.**

my code is this App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Routes from './Routes';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes/>
  );
}
```

And Route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
/// define all components here
import HomeScreen from './src/Component/HomeScreen';
import DetailScreen from './src/Component/DetailScreen';


// Routes defination
export default function Routes(){
  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Details: DetailScreen,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );
  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
  return(
    <AppContainer/>
);
}
```

And Homescreen.js from where i need this to be jump to detail screen

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

export default function HomeScreen() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>I am testing from the home screen</Text>
            <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}></Button>
        </View>
    )

}
```

And DetailScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';

export default function DetailScreen() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>I am testing from the detail screen</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `withNavigation` from react-navigation, you're seeing this error because you are not passing navigation from the parent.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

export default withNavigation(function HomeScreen() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>I am testing from the home screen</Text>
            <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}></Button>
        </View>
    )

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its fix

```
export default function HomeScreen(props) {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>I am testing from the home screen</Text>
            <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Details')}></Button>
        </View>
    )

}
```

because this.props only coming in class component but in function component its coming without a 'this'